# Add a static library in an ANE for iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, air-native-extension

I'm building an ANE for iOS platform, and I need to use a static library: libBarcodeScanner.a.

I know that when you use a framework or library that isn't on the list of frameworks that AIR links in by default, you should include it with this:

```
<platform xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/extension/3.1">
     <sdkVersion>5.1</sdkVersion>
     <linkerOptions>
          <!-- to use the CoreMotion framework -->    
          <option>-framework CoreMotion<option>
          <!-- to link with the libiconv.dylib -->
          <option>-liconv</option>
     </linkerOptions>
</platform>
```

However, the previous code is for XXX.framework, and XXX.dylib.

How should I include a XXX.a?

I've tried with -libBarcodeScanner, but when in Flash builder I export release build an app using this ANE it says that it don't find libBarcodeScanner

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you confirm that libBarcodeScanner is in your packaging directory when you build the ANE?